# Solving Math Expression in loops and storing in a dataframe with R

Tags: r, loops, math, dataframe, dplyr

The below input is the sample dataset of many rows and columns. I need to perform different math calculations by iterations on these row by row and store it in a data frame.

`A1 B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7
2   6   4   4   2   3   3   4   4   1   1   6
4   2   3   5   3   2   5   5   6   2   3   0
6   2   4   6   4   22  6   5   6   3   5   77
6   3   5   7   5   0   6   5   7   4   5   6
6   4   6   8   0   6   7   0   8   5   6   5
6   5   3   9   6   7   7   6   9   6   7   4
5   6   2   4   7   6   7   7   1   2   7   5`

For the first row I need to perform the below calculations

```
 A. A1 +    B1 + B2           + C2 + C3 + C4
 B. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3      + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5
 C. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3 +B4  + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5 +C6
```

For the second  row also  I need to perform the same calculations as first one and also for the rest of the rows

```
 A. A1 +    B1 + B2           + C2 + C3 + C4
 B. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3      + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5
 C. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3 +B4  + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5 +C6
```

The output of the result one should be in the following format

```
A   B   c
23  28  31
25  32  38
29  38  47
32  43  53
31  44  50
36  51  64
```

Can anyone please help me solve this issue  for iteration to solve  for large number of rows and columns

Comment: Sounds like matrix multiplication.

Comment: Can you help me in solving this. I am not able to figure it out how to do

Comment: Try to improve your question... What is the pattern of what you need to calculate in each row?  mean... when you say 
"For the first row I need to perform the below calculations
 A. A1 +    B1 + B2           + C2 + C3 + C4
 B. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3      + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5
 C. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3 +B4  + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5 +C6" , why the row A. skips B3 and B4? You need A. B. and C. in the same row? What exactly you need? How many rows do you expect? You need all possible combinations? Please try to make your question clearer

Comment: Please, add some details about your tries or the problem that you don't pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xx = read.table(text = "A1 B1  B2  B3  B4  C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7
2   6   4   4   2   3   3   4   4   1   1   6
4   2   3   5   3   2   5   5   6   2   3   0
6   2   4   6   4   22  6   5   6   3   5   77
6   3   5   7   5   0   6   5   7   4   5   6
6   4   6   8   0   6   7   0   8   5   6   5
6   5   3   9   6   7   7   6   9   6   7   4
5   6   2   4   7   6   7   7   1   2   7   5", header = T)

xx = as.matrix(xx)

# Create a matrix to multiply by
yy = matrix(0, nrow = ncol(xx), ncol = 3)
colnames(yy) = c("A", "B", "C")
rownames(yy) = colnames(xx)

# A. A1 +    B1 + B2           + C2 + C3 + C4
# B. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3      + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5
# C. A1 +    B1 + B2 + B3 +B4  + C2 + C3 + C4 +C5 +C6
#          A1 B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
yy[, 1] = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
yy[, 2] = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
yy[, 3] = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)

xx %*% yy
#       A  B  C
# [1,] 23 28 31
# [2,] 25 32 38
# [3,] 29 38 47
# [4,] 32 43 53
# [5,] 31 44 50
# [6,] 36 51 64
# [7,] 28 34 48
```

You could probably make a function that generates the columns of `yy` if you can describe the logic behind what terms get added for each row. This is also very flexible. The matrix used is all 1's and 0's because your linear combinations are `1 * A1 + 1 * B1 + 1 * B2 + 0 * B3 + ...`. You could use numbers other than `1` for other linear combinations.